# Correct way to make python module smaller by delegating

Tags: python, django, module, organization, code-organization

I'm trying to reduce clutter in my project's models.py and I decide to move out "utility" methods of some models.

The idea was to create a bunch of utility modules with classes and functions which will be used by model classes, but since there is no significant piece of code that doesn't use other models, it results in a circular dependence. E.g. in `models.py`:

```
from myproject import parse_util

class Entry(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    parser = parse_util.Parser(self)

    def get_some_object():
        return parser.parse_text()

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False, unique=True)
```

In `parse_util.py`:

```
from myproject.models import SomeModel

class Parser():

    def __init__(self, entry):
        self.entry = entry

    def parse_text(self):
        # parsing self.entry.text
        ...
        some_object = SomeModel.objects.get(name=parsed_value)
        return some_object
```

I can avoid it by importing `SomeModel` directly in the function, instead of doing it module-wide, or use `get_model('myapp', 'SomeModel')`. But both of these don't look good.

After the whole day in thoughts I generalised the problem: what is the correct and pythonic way (if any) to move some code coupled with another code in the module out of that module?

That is if there is a module with `classA` and `classB` and there are lengthy methods of `classB`, which use both `classA` and `classB` in some way, is there any good solution to cut down described module by splitting it into several models, but keeping entry points to `classA` and `classB` in place.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example. There are several techniques to factor out code.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: @Javier, I've updated the post with the concrete example

Comment: If you have a couple of hours you can invest, I *highly* recommend Raymond Hettinger's talks from 2015 Pycon: [Beyond PEP 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M) and [Super Considered Super](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo). They should fundamentally change the way you approach this problem.

Comment: regarding your last paragraph: so `classB` uses `classA` and `classB`, but `classA` only uses `classA`?

Comment: @dbliss, yes, the problem is to split a bigger `classB` whose methods use `classA`

Comment: @WayneWerner, thank you, I've got my answer! Mixing in Parser functionality to Entry does the job.

Comment: @TomDalton, I'm not sure, I understand how to apply this - is it like Javier's solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have the following hardcoded dependencies: Entry → Parser → SomeModel.

The way I would break the dependency is to make `Parser` generic like this:

```
class Parser(object):

    def __init__(self, entry, model):
        self.entry = entry
        self.model = model

    def parse_text(self):
        # parsing self.entry.text
        ...
        some_object = self.model.objects.get(name=parsed_value)
        return some_object
```

Now the hardcoded dependencies are just: Entry → Parser

Comment: A nice idea! This way I can pass any necessary models to utility classes as arguments.

Comment: Eventually I've just passed the whole model object to a parser